$C^k$-Norm Bounds for the Flow of an ODE
I have a question about the regularity of the flow map associated with a time-dependent ODE.
Let $v \in C^k(\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^d)$ be a time-dependent vector field mapping $(x,t) \mapsto v_t(x)$, which is continuous in $t$ and Lipschitz continuous in $x$. Consider the ODE:
\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt} x(t) = v_t(x(t)), \\
x(s) = x_s.
\end{cases}
It is well known that, for $s = 0$, there exists a flow map $\phi_t$ such that $\phi_t(x)$ gives the solution at time $t$ for initial condition $x$.
I am interested in understanding how the $C^k$-norm of the flow at a fixed time (e.g., $ \phi_1$) on $x \in [0,1]^d$ can be bounded in terms of the $C^k$-norm of the vector field $v_t$. Specifically:
Are there any general theorems or results that provide an upper bound for  $\|\phi_1\|_{C^k}$ in terms of $\|v_t\|_{C^k}$?
I understand that I can write:
\begin{align}
\phi_1(x) = x + \int_0^1 v_t(\phi_t(x)) \, dt,
\end{align}
Does this help to apply e.g. some Gronwall type inequality? Any references, insights, or pointers to relevant results would be greatly appreciated!
